# Count of strings start with particular character

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, csv

Im trying to find the count of countries start with letter V from the below List:

```
 ['USA', '249', '158', '84', '8.7'],
 ['Uruguay', '115', '35', '220', '6.6'],
 ['Uzbekistan', '25', '101', '8', '2.4'],
 ['Vanuatu', '21', '18', '11', '0.9'],
 ['Venezuela', '333', '100', '3', '7.7'],
 ['Vietnam', '111', '2', '1', '2.0'],
 ['Yemen', '6', '0', '0', '0.1'],
 ['Zambia', '32', '19', '4', '2.5'],
 ['Zimbabwe', '64', '18', '4', '4.7']
```

code:

```
def countCountry(csv1):
    count = 0
    for item in csv1:
        if '/V+' in item[0]:
            count +=1
    return count
```

unfortunately, count always returns zero. Can someone help here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why your code doesn't work as intended**

The code you wrote always return a count of zero because line 4 is never evaluated to True. Line 4 is always False because it's checking if `'/V+'`, exactly as it appears, is `in` the name of the country, which will never be the case. Moreover, you would receive a false positive if a country did exist with a name as outlandish as `'Japmeri/V+na'`

```
1. def countCountry(csv1):
2.    count = 0
3.    for item in csv1:
4.        if '/V+' in item[0]:
5.            count +=1
6.    return count
```

**The fix**

Here is how you can make your code better, and I'll go further than the previous answers to make it more readable and robust.

```
def countCountry(csv1):
    count = 0
    for item in csv1:
        country_name = item[0].lower() # to ensure you're always checking against lowercase
        if country_name.startswith('v'): # so that it's easy to read
            count +=1
    return count
```

I hope this answers your question. Happy coding!

Answer (score 5):

Just `sum(1 for row in csv if row[0][0] == 'V')`.

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer, provide more details.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `startswith`:

```
def countCountry(csv1):
    count = 0
    for item in csv1:
        if item[0].startswith('V'):
            count +=1
    return count

print countCountry(a)
```

Or:

```
def countCountry(csv1):
    return sum([True for i in csv1 if i[0].startswith('V')])

print countCountry(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> if '/V+' in item[0]:
> ```

Python doesn't use slashes to indicate a regex, and `in` performs an exact search. Either import and use `re` or use `str.startswith()` as the other answers suggest.

Comment: I got it. Thank you @Ignacio. Appreciate it

Comment: And `/V+/` would be a really poor regex if the intent is to match simply `/^V/`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `startswith`

```
def countCountry(csv1):
    count = 0
    for item in csv1:
        if item[0].startswith('V'):
            count +=1
    return count
```

or you can use regex using `re`:

```
def countCountry(csv1):
    count = 0
    for item in csv1:
        if re.match(r'V', item[0]):
            count +=1
    return count
```